# Is it possible to setup a custom hostname for AWS Transfer SFTP via Terraform

Tags: sftp, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to set up an SFTP server with a custom hostname using AWS Transfer. I'm managing the resource using Terraform. I've currently got the resource up and running, and I've used Terraform to create a Route53 record to point to the SFTP server, but the custom hostname entry on the SFTP dashboard is reading as blank.
[image]

And of course, when I create the server manually throught the AWS console and associate a route53 record with it, it looks like what I would expect:
[image]

I've looked through the [terraform resource documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/transfer_server.html) and I've tried to see how it might be done via aws cli or cloudformation, but I haven't had any luck.

My server resource looks like:

```
resource "aws_transfer_server" "sftp" {
  identity_provider_type = "SERVICE_MANAGED"
  logging_role           = "${aws_iam_role.logging.arn}"
  force_destroy          = "false"

  tags {
    Name = ${local.product}-${terraform.workspace}"
  }
}
```

and my Route53 record looks like:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "dns_record_cname" {
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.sftp.zone_id}"
  name    = "${local.product}-${terraform.workspace}"
  type    = "CNAME"
  records = ["${aws_transfer_server.sftp.endpoint}"]
  ttl = "300"
}
```

Functionally, I can move forward with what I have, I can connect to the server with my DNS, but I'm trying to understand the complete picture.

Comment: Seems it is not ready for this feature. This is very new terraform resource, maybe you can raise PR to add the feature to manage the `custom hostname`.

Comment: You're right. After checking the Github for Terraform AWS Provider, I see an open issue raised for it. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/6956

Comment: actually, that ticket is now closed. This is the new place to track this (still open...) issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/18077

Comment: As long as the AWS Transfer Family API does not support this (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/API_CreateServer.html) your best bet is to go with the workaround mentioned in the two GitHub issues mentioned in the the comments above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/requirements-dns.html#tag-custom-hostname-cdk),

> When you create a server using AWS Cloud Development Kit (AWS CDK) or through the CLI, you must add a tag if you want that server to have a custom hostname. When you create a Transfer Family server by using the console, the tagging is done automatically.

So, you will need to be able to add those tags using Terraform. In [v4.35.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/releases/tag/v4.35.0) they added support for a new resource: [aws_transfer_tag](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/18077).

[An example supplied in the GitHub Issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/18077#issuecomment-1273904488):

```
resource "aws_transfer_server" "with_custom_domain" {
  # config here
}

resource "aws_transfer_tag" "with_custom_domain_route53_zone_id" {
  resource_arn = aws_transfer_server.with_custom_domain.arn
  key          = "aws:transfer:route53HostedZoneId"
  value        = "/hostedzone/ABCDE1111222233334444"
}

resource "aws_transfer_tag" "with_custom_domain_name" {
  resource_arn = aws_transfer_server.with_custom_domain.arn
  key          = "aws:transfer:customHostname"
  value        = "abc.example.com"
}
```